# How should Muscari be kept  so that they grow well next year?

Tags: bulbs

I planted some muscari and they flowered successfully with two flowers per bulb. Now the flowers have wilted. How should I keep them in order to make them grow next year? The leaves are still there and I've cut the flowers so that they don't drain energy anymore.

I am in Hong Kong which is a subtropical area. Please give advice for the sub-tropics as I know muscari originated from colder places which suit them better.

Answer (score 3):

When winter comes, dig the bulbs up, trim off the leaves, and wrap in newspaper. Then put them in the refrigerator  to break the dormancy. Leave them in for 8 weeks, then plant back in the garden.